# Unexpected closing parentheses in batch file with matching start

Tags: batch-file, command-line, parentheses

I have a simple batch file that currently all it does it tries to connect to a wifi network up to 10 times.

My trouble is that I am getting an unexpected output in my command prompt when it is ran.

Here is my batch script

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
echo.
echo.

:startSetVariables
set timeout="2"
set PINGS="4"
set pingtimeout="1000"
set endonfail="10"
set wifissid="ROGAR Production"
set /A COUNTER=1

:connectToTheInternet
echo checking internet connection
echo.
:connectToTheInternetRestart
ping -n 1 host | find /i "TTL=" >NUL && (
    echo Internet connection already established, skipping to activation!
    echo.
    goto endNoShutdown
    ::toupd
) || ( 
    ::if failed endonfail times, give up
    if "%COUNTER%"=="%endonfail%" (
        echo Error: Could not connect to network %endonfail% times, stopping script.
        echo.
        goto endNoShutdown
    )

    ::raise waiting time between connections        
    if "%COUNTER%"=="3" (
        echo failed 2 times in a row. Increasing wait time between actions to 4 seconds.
        echo.
        set timeout=4
        set /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1
    ) else if "%COUNTER%"=="5" (
        echo failed 4 times in a row. Increasing wait time between actions to 6 seconds.
        echo.
        set timeout=6
        set /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1
    ) else if "%COUNTER%"=="7" (
        echo failed 6 times in a row. Increasing wait time between actions to 8 seconds.
        echo.
        set timeout=8
        set /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1
    ) else if "%COUNTER%"=="9" (
        echo failed 8 times in a row. Increasing wait time between actions to 10 seconds.
        echo.
        set timeout=10
        set /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1
    ) else (
        echo Wait time is currently %timeout% seconds.
        set /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1
    )

    echo Attempt #%COUNTER%.

    ::disconnect existing network
    netsh wlan disconnect
    netsh wlan delete profile name="%wifissid%"

    timeout /t 1 /nobreak

    echo.
    ::attempt connection
    netsh wlan add profile filename="connection.xml"
    netsh wlan connect name="%wifissid%" ssid="%wifissid%"

    timeout /t %timeout% /nobreak

    ::check connection
    set internet=false
    Ping google.com -n 1 -w %pingtimeout%
    if errorlevel 1 (
        set internet=Failed
    ) else (
        set internet=Connected
    )

    ::check pings
    ping -n 1 host | find /i "TTL=" >NUL && (
        echo Successfully connected! Starting activation check.
        echo.
        goto endNoShutdown
        ::toupd
    ) || ( 
        echo Connection attempt failed. Starting attempt #%COUNTER% in 3 seconds.
        echo.
        timeout /t 3 /nobreak
        cls
        goto connectToTheInternetRestart
    )
)


:endShutdown
echo Releasing wifi, shutting down computer.
netsh wlan delete profile name="%wifissid%"
pause
shutdown /s

:endNoShutdown
echo Releasing wifi, ending without shutdown.
netsh wlan delete profile name="%wifissid%"
```

I believe every opening parentheses has a partner closing parentheses, but my output says otherwise.

Here is my output (I've disabled @ECHO OFF to see where the error actually starts. (o) stands for actual output):

```
>set /A COUNTER=1
>echo checking internet connection
checking internet connection (o)

>echo.

Ping google.com -n 1 -w 1000
Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again. (o - should return errorlevel 1, meaning the following should resolve to else)
>echo Internet access: Failed
Internet access: Failed (o)

>echo.

) was unexpected at this time. (o)

>     ) || (
```

Then the script ends without anything else.

Comment: You're going to have an expansion problem with `timeout /t %timeout% /nobreak`.  You need to delay expansion of `%timeout%` there.  Also, there are some circumstances where a ping will receive replies from a gateway interface reading "no route to host"; but having received responses, errorlevel will be 0.  You should `ping -n 1 host | find /i "TTL=" >NUL && ( success code block ) || ( fail code block )`.  And replace all your `::` comments with `rem`.  `::` doesn't belong inside a parenthetical code block, and can have consequences.  Indeed, that might be causing the `) was unexpected` error.

Comment: @rojo I saw someone suggest using EnableDelayedExpansion to fix a similar issue that I have. It didn't work, but I will keep it enabled & I will update my statements to what your suggestion is.

Comment: @rojo now it says `) was unexpected at this time.` and then the next input is `) || (`. I'm beginning to think it is taking the `else` paremeters as commands? Updated answer with new code.

Comment: Did you replace your `::comments` with `rem comments` yet?

Comment: @rojo I hadn't known to do that, one sec please.

Comment: @rojo that seems to have done it. I didn't know there was a difference between the commands?

Comment: `::` isn't a command.  It's a label.  But labels don't belong inside a parenthetical code block.

Comment: @rojo oh my goodness. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `::` comments aren't really comments.  They're labels.  But labels don't belong inside parenthetical code blocks.  Use `rem` instead, and that should get rid of your `) was unexpected at this time` problem.

You might also consider condensing your script with a `for /L` loop -- something like this, for example:

```js
for /L %%I in (1,1,10) do (
    ping -n 1 www.google.com | find /i "TTL=" >NUL && (

        echo Successfully connected.
        goto :EOF

    ) || (

        set /a delay = %%I - 1
        echo Starting attempt %%I in !delay! seconds.

        >NUL 2>NUL (
            rem // disconnecting first...
            netsh wlan disconnect
            netsh wlan delete profile name="%wifissid%"

            timeout /t 1 /nobreak

            rem // attempting reconnection...
            netsh wlan add profile filename="connection.xml"
            netsh wlan connect name="%wifissid%" ssid="%wifissid%"

            timeout /t !delay! /nobreak
        )
    )
)
```