# timeout command in batch file with wrong seconds value

Tags: batch-file

I'm doing a loop to check the battery status of a windows tablet. Therefore I wait 20 seconds to controll the battery status.

when I call

`TIMEOUT /T 20 /NOBREAK`

it works on 20 tablets perfecly. on one tablet I'm getting sometimes the callback "Waiting 12328783 seconds, press..."  the seconds value is a huge value...

why this tablet callback a total wrong waitng time?

Comment: possibly [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619274/batch-file-timeout-command-jumping-to-10k-30k-40k-seconds?rq=1) - maybe `choice` solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is that the machine is using something other than **timeout.exe**, *probably a batch file with the name timeout.bat or timeout.cmd*.

To fix this change the command to read:

```bat
TIMEOUT.EXE /T 20 /NOBREAK
```

Or:

```bat
"%__APPDIR__%TIMEOUT.EXE" /T 20 /NOBREAK
```

Comment: this happens not every time, In 4 of 5 cases it works fine.

Comment: If using the options I have provided does not fix the issue you reported then the issue becomes a computer one, not a script/coding one, and is out of the scope of this site.